# Run Yarn tasks from a parent directory

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, yarnpkg

I have a project that contains several sub projects, one of which is a JavaScript project. I want to use the JavaScript project as a task runner for the entire project via `gulp` but I'm running into some trouble.

My project structure is essentially:

```
root 
     |_
       js-client 
                |_
                   package.json
                |_
                   node_modules
     |_
       go-server
```

I've determined that `.yarnrc` can be used to specify a different `node_modules` location, so I moved `package.json` to the `root` directory and created this `.yarnrc` file:

```
--modules-folder client/node_modules
```

Now when I run `yarn install` from the root directory, the modules do get installed exactly as I expect in the specified location but when I run `yarn build` I get this error:

```
[09:46:17] Local modules not found in ~/Documents/Projects/root
[09:46:17] Try running: npm install
```

I'm guessing this means `--modules-folder` is only used as a flag for `install` and not for `run`. Is what I'm trying to do possible, or do I just have to create a separate yarn project to run tasks? I'd rather not rely on global to accomplish this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is to run yarn with `--cwd`

This changes yarn's working directory to whatever you specify

So for the example above, to run `yarn build` from the root directory, you would type:

`yarn --cwd js-client build`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a build script in your package.json?

If not, I would add it to your package.json to overwrite the default behavior and start the script with something like: `cd client && yarn build`.

Edit:

```
root
--package.json (with the build script)
--client
```

Comment: yeah I do, the point is that I want to be able to run it from outside the client folder though

Comment: Can you share your package.json?